# Any idea what i'm doing wrong? NODEJS

Tags: node.js

```
    ...     



 if (response.summ > check) {
    io.emit('acceptoffer', {steamid: offer.steamid_other})
helper.msg('More Than Min - ' + offer.tradeofferid);

if(timer <= 28 && timer != 0) {
offers.declineOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid}, function() {
currentGameOffers.splice(currentGameOffers.indexOf(offer.tradeofferid), 1);
helper.msg('Timer less than 28 seconds - ' + offer.tradeofferid);

} else {
try {
offers.acceptOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid}, function(err,     log) {

if (err) { 


...
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong over here?

the error i get is that

```
} else {
  ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token else
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

What i'm trying to do is if the timer on the javascript is <=28 and <> from 0 then do offer.declineOffer and if its not run the offer.AcceptOffer.

I'm really sorry if i didnt supose to post it here and i'm also sorry for my english.

Comment: Your try/catch is superfluous as it's an async call.

Comment: Check starting / closing braces for if-else.

Comment: You should take more care about indentation in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an open `(` from `offers.declineOffer` and an open `{` from your `if` block. You should format your code to see the problem:

```
if (response.summ > check) {
    io.emit('acceptoffer', {steamid: offer.steamid_other})
    helper.msg('More Than Min - ' + offer.tradeofferid);

    if (timer <= 28 && timer != 0) {
        offers.declineOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid}, function () { // starts a function definition
            currentGameOffers.splice(currentGameOffers.indexOf(offer.tradeofferid), 1);
            helper.msg('Timer less than 28 seconds - ' + offer.tradeofferid);

        } // closes the function definition
    // OOPS! There's no } to close the if block.
    // You also need to close the ( from offers.declineOffer
    // Add the ) and } here, like this:
        );
    }
    else
        {
            try {
                offers.acceptOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid}, function (err, log) {

                    if (err) {
```

Comment: That actually returned a new error saying that (Sorry for posting link) i'm not sure how it will show it here http://pastebin.com/JqxZC0Uu

Comment: @ΓιώργοςΓεωργίου Are you sure that 's in the same code block? The code in my answer is correct according to my IDE, so it's likely the new error is from a different piece of code.

Comment: You are right. Now its return in a new part of the code   http://pastebin.com/hPE83p6p

Comment: @ΓιώργοςΓεωργίου In that case, you should accept one of the answers to your question because you have solved your initial problem. Then, ask a new question using the ["Ask Question" button at the top of the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, rephrase your question before it gets too many downvotes and gets buried under, umm, something. Proper sentences are required to understand the question and intent of question, so that others can help you.

You have added `else` to closing brace for the `function`.

Instead try:

```
...
    })
} else {
...
```

HTH